# How do I get my monitor to go in standby when my computer is off or sleeping?

Tags: windows, display, hdmi, desktop

**Brief description of the problem:**
Whenever I turn my computer OFF or into sleep mode, the monitor does not go into standby mode, and shows "No signal" indefinitely.

I recently changed computer and the old computer did not have this problem.

**Computer details:**

- Monitor : Samsung curved monitor (LC27F390HUXEN), connected via HDMI.
- CPU : i3-4170
- Motherboard : MSI h81m-e34
- SSD : Kingston SA400S37480G
- Power supply : Advance 450 watts (don't remember the model).
- Graphics card : GTX 660.
- OS : Windows 10

This computer was built out of parts I got for free so it has a weird configuration (graphics card is older than the rest of the PC, cheap power supply).

**Behavior of the old computer**:
When the old computer was off or in sleep mode, the monitor would automatically go into standby mode.
When the computer was turned back on, the monitor would also turn on.
This was very convenient as I did not have to press a button on the monitor.

**Behavior of the new computer:**
The new computer no longer does that.
When the computer is turned off or sleeping, the monitor goes into standby mode for 10 seconds or so, and then switches back on showing "No signal".
I then need to manually switch the monitor off.

The next time I use the computer, I have to manually switch the monitor ON, and it shows "No signal".
When I switch the computer ON, the monitor goes into standby mode for 10 seconds or so, and then it displays an image.

If I do not interact with the computer for a few minutes, the monitor goes into standby mode and it switches back on when I move the mouse or press a key on the keyboard (expected behavior)

**More details:**
So far, it seems like the computer can tell the monitor to go in and out of standby mode, however the monitor goes out of standby mode whenever the computer is off or sleeping.

More precisely, the monitor goes out of standby mode and shows "No signal" whenever the computer is silent, that is, when the power supply is OFF (power supply fan not running)

**Attempts to fix the problem:**
There seems to be no settings related to this in Windows, apart for turning the monitor or the computer off after a defined time of inactivity.  There are also no settings related to this in the monitor's settings menu or in the graphics card control panel.
I tried changing some settings in the BIOS but I did not find anything that could fix the problem.

When searching for this issue on the Internet, I found many people asking about the monitor not going into standby mode after some time of inactivity, however I found none asking about my exact issue.

**What is probably happening:**
As far as I understand the problem : the monitor automatically goes into standby mode when two conditions are met :

1. The monitor detects that it is connected to the computer
2. The monitor detects that the computer is not sending any signal

Which would mean that :

1. When the computer is ON (power supply ON), the monitor is able to detect that it it still connected to the computer, and goes into standby mode when the computer stops sending the HDMI signal.
2. When the computer is OFF or sleeping (power supply OFF), the monitor believes that it is no longer connected to the computer, and shows "No signal" indefinitely.

**What I would like to know :**

- Have you experienced the same problem and if so, did you manage to fix it ?
- Where do you think the problem is coming from : Windows, BIOS, motherboard, graphics card, power supply ?
- Am I right about how the computer puts the monitor into standby mode? Does it just stops sending the HDMI signal or does it send some sort of "message" through the HDMI cable ?

**EDIT:**
I tried connecting the monitor to the motherboard's HDMI port. I get no picture, however the monitor does go into standby mode. I will try to use the GPU with the motherboard's HDMI port.

**EDIT 2:**:
According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1448478/hdmi-device-detection-should-the-turning-off-of-one-device-be-recognized-as-un) the monitor detects that it is plugged into the computer when it detects +5V on the pin 18 of the HDMI port.
So the cause of my problem is that my graphics card does not provide the 5V standby when it is off. I will try to find if this is a configuration problem, a hardware problem or if it's just designed this way.

Comment: Please provide full details.  Computer details, OS details, monitor details, cable details (is it HDMI to HDMI) etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What happens when you unplug the monitor from the computer? Does it still do this? I have one computer for whatever reason still sends power out on the HDMI even with the computer shutdown.

Comment: @techloom The monitor shows "No signal" if it is unplugged or when the computer is off.

Answer (score 0):

Other users with the same GPU report some similar behavior on a particular motherboard and not on an alternative motherboard: https://www.tweaktownforum.com/forum/tech-support-from-vendors/asrock/52579-monitor-won-t-wake-after-s3-sleep-with-gtx-660-ti

In my experience, this type of behavior is generally caused by a power setting or behavior of the motherboard BIOS. If you're not on the latest version of your motherboard's BIOS/UEFI, you may want to update to the latest and see if the behavior matches your expectations: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H81M-E34/support

You may also find a power setting that allows the more appropriate suspend behavior, although the manual is too light on details to offer step-by-step instructions, look for settings related to suspend behavior (rather than CPU power saving features).

There is also a VBIOS (GPU firmware) component to the suspend behavior, but it's generally harder to find an appropriate VBIOS update and tool and the process is much riskier than updating the motherboard firmware unless you have an official tool from NVIDIA or the GPU vendor.